# iOS 8.4 / iOS 9 - Strange bug music app

Tags: itunes, music.app, ios

Recently with the new music app introduced by iOS 8.4, I get strange bugs

**Bug 1**

While songs are played in shuffle/random mode .

When playing songs from all tracks in shuffle mode, just after listening to songs from a playlist whatever the mode (shuffle or normal mode), the third track played is the last track listenned from the playlist.

**How to reproduce Bug 1**

1. Play songs from a playlist
2. Go to 'Songs' and play all songs in shuffle mode.
3. listen or skip the first track
4. listen or skip the second track
5. The third track should be the last track played from step 1.

**Bug 2**

When playing songs from an intelligent playlist (playlist with rules ⚙) with a rule that removes the last song played (see below to reproduce the bug), if I pause play, put the iPod into sleep mode, then recover play, songs that are removed from the playlist are played.

**How to reproduce Bug 2**

1. Create a playlist with all songs never played in the last month.
2. Sync the playlist with your iOS device
3. Play couple of song from this playlist (playlist should update by removing played songs)
4. Pause play
5. Put iOS device into sleep mode
6. Wait somme minutes
7. Recover play
8. Songs that are removed from the playlist should play

Am I the only one to have these bugs ?
If someone get these bugs, is there a fix ?

Thanks

**PS**

- I use an iPod touch 5th gen 64gb and I have more than 4000 songs from various artists and genres, with good metadata.
- Bugs happened also on iOS 9.
- I have tried to kill the Music app still got the problem.
- I don't have an Apple Music subscription.

Comment: This isn't that much of a question... but either way, you should report the bugs at [https://bugreport.apple.com](https://bugreport.apple.com)

Comment: As the bug where not so hard to reproduce (at least the first one) I would like to know if someone already notice one of them. I will report these two bugs to apple.